# Continuity of projections

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, continuity, convex-analysis

Suppose  $X$ is a convex compact subset in $\mathbb R^n$, $n\geq 2$ and $x^*\in\mathbb R^n$ satisfying $x^*\notin X$.

For $p\in \mathbb R^n_{++}$, define the $p$-inner product by

$$\langle x,y \rangle_p= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i p_i$$

and the minimum $p$-norm by

$$\pi(p,X, x^*)=\arg\min_{x\in X} \|  x^*-x\|_p$$

Suppose    the normal vector

$$\lambda(p)= x^*-\pi(p,X, x^*)\in \mathbb R_+^n\setminus\{0\}$$

Can I always find a sequence $(p_k)_{k\geq 1}\in \mathbb R^{n}_{++}$,  and $p_k\to p$ such that

$$\lambda(p_k)= x^*-\pi(p_k,X, x^*)\in\mathbb R^n_{++}$$

for all $k\geq 1$?

Thanks.

Comment: No. If $X$ is a singleton, $\pi(p,X,x^*)$ does not depend on $p$.